# File copy from a physical server to a server in cloud is that considered egress or ingress?

Tags: windows, networking, azure-networking

If I'm copying files from on-prem Server to a Server on cloud via VPN,  is it considered egress traffic?

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to ask a "costing" question about whether it will cost you for file copies in/out of the cloud...

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to understand the cost since azure does not charge for Ingress in my case data flow between Azure servers and on-premise servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're copying file from on-prem server to a cloud server, the egress traffic is considered from the on-prem side, and the ingress traffic is considered from the cloud server side.

Otherwise, If you're copying a file from a cloud server to an on-prem server, the egress traffic is considered from the cloud side, and the ingress traffic is considered from the on-prem server side.

Regards.